# Search and Highlight text in PDF for IPad

Tags: objective-c

I am working on the PDF App for iPad and facing an issue: how to search a text in PDF and also how to highlight that text?

Answer (score 1):

Yours is the same big problem I'm having. My understanding is that, currently on iOS 4.0, the main public API is [CGPDF](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html) . It allows us to parse PDF, and with it we can search strings in it. See also this [Quartz 2D](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-TPXREF101) document. It also allows us to render it on the screen using [CGContextDrawPage](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextDrawPDFPage). However, it's not yet possible to get the position of a text in the rendered image. (On OS X it's possible using [PDFKit](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/PDFKit_Ref/index.html).)

So, I'm afraid that you need to implement the [PDF spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) yourself to get that info. I think GoodReader etc. is working very very hard to implement these.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same trouble recently and then I found FastPDFKit. Have tested the package and it's working great.

http://mobfarm.eu/fastpdfkit